# EditText all possible number in random output in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android. I'm developing an app which gives all the possible combination number based on the user input and separated it by comma.

---

For example the user input is: 1234
The output should be list all the possible number combination from "1234" like 
"1234,1243,1324,1342,1423,1432,2134,etc.."

---

And there's also another EditText that limit the output by setting it to 1 or 2 or 3 or 4(max).
For example the user input is: 2
The output should be list all the possible number combination from "1234" by "2" digits
"12,13,14,21,23,24,31,32,34,41,42,43"

---

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidtest1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et_input1, et_output1;
    Button b_generate, b_clear;
    CheckBox checkBox1;
    Random r;
    int min,output;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_output1);
        mEdit.setEnabled(false);

        r = new Random();

        et_input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input1);
        et_output1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_output1);
        b_generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_generate);
        b_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_clear);
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        b_generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (et_input1.length()==0){
                  et_input1.setError("Insert numbers");

            }else if(checkBox1.isChecked()){
                    min = Integer.parseInt(et_input1.getText().toString());
                    output = (min);
                    et_output1.setText("" + output + "*");
                    et_input1.setError(null);
                }
                else{
                    et_input1.setError("Check the checkbox");
                }

            }
        });

        b_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_output1.getText().clear();
                et_input1.getText().clear();
                return;
            }
        });
           }
    }
```

Comment: Your `mEdit` and `et_output1` variables are duplicative. Delete 1 of them. You later call `.length()` on an instance of `EditText`. This won't work. You need to get the value from the instance first and then check its length.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? on codes.The one with the instance algorithm to make my output wants works.It's just  I'm beginner on android studio and just start learning recently. Thanks.

Comment: Like this : `et_input1.getText().toString().length()`. You pull the value out of the `EditText` like this later in your code.

Comment: Um.. what exactly is your problem? You have posted your code and all, but what is the question?

Comment: Also what is the intention of this line `output = (min);`

Comment: My question is how am i gonna do that with my current codes that example out i stated above.My fault on "output = (min)" i forgot to delete this one, this was supposed to handle the random numbers before.

Comment: Also it was like get Permutation on java console. Is it possible to work on android by the use of editText output?